# AWS: cannot reach ec2 hosts through Sonicwall VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, amazon-web-services, sonicwall

```
 ----<--<-<-<-------  HQ <- .-> AWS --->-------->-->-->-->---------
                            .        eth0(X1) WAN
+---------------------+     .      +---------------+
| HQ 172.99.2.0/24    +===VPN=======               +             +-------+                        .
+---------------------+     .      +  sonicwall    ==============|  H1   |                      .
                            .      +---------------+    vpc/13   +-------+                       . 
                            .        eth1(X0) LAN                 172.13.1.6                  .
                            .        172.13.1.109
```

Working:

- ping from HQ to sonicwall X0
- ping from sonicwall X0 to HQ
- https from HQ to sonicwall X0
- ping from sonicwall to H1
- ping from H1 to sonicwall

NOT working:

- ping from HQ to H1
- ping from H1 to HQ

We've got a Sonicwall NSA 270 appliance running on EC2. It has got 2 interfaces, one eth0(X1) for the WAN side , and one the LAN side eth1(X0) vpc/13 private IP 172.13.1.109

On our HQ we have got a LAN network 172.99.2.0/23

The Sonicwall has got a site-to-site VPN tunnel between our HQ's LAN 172.99.2.0/23 and the Sonicwall's X0 network 172.13.1.0/24

With the VPN tunnel up and running, I can ping 172.13.1.109 from our HQ and access the web interface on 172.13.1.109.

I have got an EC2 server, H1, with an interface on VPC/13, and IP address 172.13.1.6

I can ping the firewall's LAN IP address from that server
(ping 172.13.1.109 ←→ 172.13.1.6 works)

However, I *cannot* ping from the HQ Lan to the EC2 server, nor pass any other kind of traffic, like SSH or HTTP.

I have allowed all traffic on the VPC, I have tried to add static routes on the AWS subnets, I have explicitly added
a Allow ALL Traffic from anywhere to anywhere on the Sonicwall. but it just does. not. want. to. pass. traffic!

Answer (score -1):

I have a feeling one of these support articles will help you:

https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/traffic-not-passing-through-the-site-to-site-vpn-tunnel/170505273989928/

https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/route-traffic-to-certain-website-s-through-site-to-site-vpn-without-route-all-traffic-vpn-set/170503510565981/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1087905)

Comment: Yeah, I definitely evaluated that before posting. It's just that the answers in these links are very detailed and somewhat complex - including screenshots. So it would be difficult to really replicate them here in a useful way.